# IBM MQ issue with 32-bit operating system(not able to connect)

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

There is an issue i am facing with 32-bit windows OS(windows xp) when connected with IBM MQ 7.1 client.

I am using 7.1.0.0 amqmdnet.dll (referenced from IBM\websphere\bin folder)

```
<Reference Include="amqmdnet, Version=7.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=da2dc1d9abf9ed97, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..IBM\WebSphereMQ\7.1.0.0\amqmdnet.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

(downloaded from [IBM link](https://www14.software.ibm.com/))

and building my .net app using MQ.NET classes, however after deployment, if the target machine has 7.1.0.0 MQ client installed, the app throws

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqz.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

```
  at NativeUnmanagedType.zstSPI(Int32 hConn, Int32 verbId, Int32 hObj, Byte[] pInOut, Byte[] pIn, Byte[] pOut, Int32& compCode, Int32& reason)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.SPIQuerySPI(Hconn hConn, Int32 verbId, Int32& maxInOutVersion, Int32& maxInVersion, Int32& maxOutVersion, Int32& flags, Int32& pCompCode, Int32& pReason)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.MQCONNX(String pQMgrName, MQCNO& pConnectOpts, Hconn parentHconn, Phconn phconn, Int32& pCompCode, Int32& pReason)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.MQCONNX(String pQMgrName, MQConnectOptions pConnectOpts, Phconn phconn, Int32& pCompCode, Int32& pReason)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)
```

My code is

```
// mq properties
properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "Connection Name");
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, "Transport Type");
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "Channel Name"); 
properties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK);

//To read the messages
mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();

if (mqQueue != null)
            {
                //Get options for the messsage                
                mqGetMsgOpts.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST | MQC.MQGMO_WAIT |  MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;
                mqGetMsgOpts.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;
                mqGetMsgOpts.WaitInterval = 5000;  // 5 seconds limit for waiting
            }

      if (mqMsg.MessageLength > 0 && mqMsg.DataLength > 0)
      {
        messageData = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);
      }
```

There is browse_next after queue manager commit is called(so browse the next messsage).

```
//To put the message
if(mqQueue==null)   
mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue("Queue Name",
 MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);

    mqMsg.WriteString(message);
```

How do i resolve that error, any idea? The same piece of code works fine windows 64-bit OS. I don't have that mqz.dll inside bin folder in 64-bit OS's websphere MQ client installation folder, there it works, however it fails iin 32-bit OS.

Comment: Any inputs might help?

Answer (score 1):

I just install MQ v71 client on a 64 bit machine. I can see MQZ.DLL in both `Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin` and `Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64` folders.

Have you **installed** the MQ v71 client on the WinXP machine?

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded v7.1.0.0 for windows, from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031412, i don't see mqz.dll(however i see mqzsd.dll), can you share me the link from where you downloaded? I have installed MQ v7.1.0.0 in winXP machine, i am getting, mqz.dll not found.

Comment: If, i install in a 64-bit machine, although i don't have MQZ.dll in bin folders, it works there, however, when i install the same MQ client 7.1.0.0 in 32-bit machine, i get dll not found for MQZ.dll(no MQZ.dll in bin folder).

Comment: I installed from the same link as you. I just picked MQ v7.1.0.2 Clients as that's the latest fixpack.

Comment: It worked for me too with 7.1.0.2, however, i am facing issue in 32-bit OS with 7.1.0.0.

Comment: If it's working with 7102 then go with that. That's the latest fixpack of 7.1.